# Could edible fish live in a large water tank used as a radiation shield on a spacecraft?

Tags: science-fiction, hard-science, spaceships, generation-ships, radiation

As a source of food, would it be possible to have fish and/or plants living inside a water tank situated between the fusion or fission power plant and the crew quarters of a ship?

The ship in question is a mining barge operating in the asteroid belt, although the idea may be transferrable to interstellar craft as well.

The water supply would also be used to provide fuel for thrusters and engines, as well as for drinking water (using reverse osmosis and mixed-bed filters to purify it). Additionally, the refining process would use large amounts of water.

The water supply would be replenished from asteroids.

Would a lining or special construction material be required to assist in radiation shielding? Ideally something available in the asteroid belt, or refinable in space.

The timeframe is within the next two centuries or so.

I'm looking at a crew size of around 20-30. A semi-automated mining and refinery vessel. No main engines, designed to be moved to new locations by the eccentric orbit of the asteroid currently being mined, and by tugs. So mass and inertia would be an issue, hence looking at a multi-use shield.

Personal note: I worked 1000km into the desert at a nickel and cobalt mine and refinery. About the only things we had to bring in from outside were natural gas and sulphur. Everything else, we provided "in-house", including water.

The water came from underground bores, very high in calcium and other trace elements. It was stored in dams, which had fish, weeds, small crustaceans like lobsters, dead birds and lizards, frogs, you name it. We had our own water treatment plant. "Raw" or untreated water could be used for many of the refinery processes without any problem.

After reverse osmosis, we had potable water for drinking, and safety showers. It was extremely low in impurities, much lower than city water.

After mixed bed filtering (using cat ion/an ion filtering), we had demineralised water.  Fewer impurities than bottled distilled water from the supermarket, and useful for running through equipment that might otherwise have been affected by impurities (boilers and steam turbines for example).

Another note: I was at Chernobyl a few years ago, well after the reactor explosion. From my limited understanding, the greatest threat came from actual particles of dirt or sand that could stick to your clothes or be ingested with food or from smoking cigarettes/touching your mouth.

There were many places even within the reactor building itself where people continue to work right now. Other areas were strictly off limits for the next 2,000 years.

Moss, for example was a big no-no. It seemed to absorb radiation. Cats, dogs and other feral animals were not to be touched at all, as they were high enough up the food chain to be affected by eating smaller animals, as well as rolling around in radioactive dirt.

Something like 2,500 people still work at Chernobyl, and only wear protective suits in the bad areas (relying on dosimeter badges on their clothes, and testing themselves when they return to their offices).

Comment: just stick to fusion reactor and you can keep your fishes inside freezer...

Comment: @user6760 frozen fish don't procreate...

Comment: @Burki: how bout cloning fish eggs with frozen embryos...

Comment: @user6760 just letting them procreate naturally requires a lot less tech. The fish even bring their own procreation experts. ;-)

Comment: @Burki: you are right I also loved to see how fish do it!

Comment: Maybe go with a fusion reactor (no need for shielding) and concentrate your shielding on the exterior of the spaceship so as to block all the nasty space radiation? Then your question makes more sense imho.

Comment: @Burki My thoughts exactly. An eco system inside a water tank could provide a food source.

Comment: @Seleong I could go with a fusion reactor (One of the joys of science fiction is that, even if we don't have the technology today, tomorrow we may have). The space radiation is another bridge I may have to cross.

Comment: @Smoj After the fusion experiment the other day, it could be available sooner than thought. Space radiation from solar flares (or getting to close to Jupiter) would be a lot bigger deal.

Comment: The amount of insulation and the amount of protection from space debris might negate the usefulness of this as protection from your folks.

Comment: Either you use the water for fish, or for shielding. If you use it for both, your fish will be poisonous.

Comment: @Mikey Actually, it's a pretty interesting shielding idea if you don't have to worry about getting all that weight into orbit. If you get a hull breach, it'll freeze, sealing the hole.

Comment: @Nobody You'd definitely need to layer it. You could have a smaller breed of fish bred for the outside layer that's a food source for the inner and dilute it while maximizing space that way.

Comment: @liljoshu Umm, no. From the lowest contaminated spot in the foodchain upwards you have a problem. So no matter which fish are in the area which is serving as a radiation-shield, humans, as the top of this foodchain, get contaminated food.

Comment: @Nobody Fair enough, radiation can stick around. But at low enough levels, it's not harmful. I'm not saying having the larger ecosystem feed exclusively on the outer layer, but allow in just enough to suppelment without pushing the final radiation dosage beyond acceptable limits.

Comment: @liljoshu The mass of the water is always going to be an issue, but the barge will be constructed away from planetary gravity  and will stay pretty much in the asteroid belt. The reactors would be to power the process and life support. I figured that the barge needs water, food, fuel and shielding. Might as well cover as many bases as possible with a medium that serves multiple purposes for the same mass penalty.

Comment: @Nobody The catalyst for my original question was my time at Chernobyl where it seemed that the greatest danger for radioactive cross contamination came from particulate matter. Dust or grains of dirt picked up on your shoes, breathed in to your lungs etc. The radiation itself from the reactor would just pass straight through you with little residual radiation left in the body. But 20 years later, you have an endocrine system collapse. Incidentally, they found that the occurrences of genetic mutation amongst flora and fauna in the area was actually lower than the statistical norm elsewhere.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, but why would you?

The water in question is being used to absorb ionising radiation, so the fish will also get a fairly high dose if they live near the outer wall. This is fine if you split the tank, perhaps having the outer half as a filtration system (for reasons I'm about to dive into), but could lead to a high rate of piscine mortality or genetic degradation in the fish stocks.

The main issue here is that *fish poop*. Your nice, clean water source for fuel, coolant, drinking, everything is now contaminated with the various and sundry byproducts of fish. You'll already have had to filter, clean and chemically balance the water once before feeding it into your tanks (heavy metals, wrong acidity, all sorts of things can kill fish), and then you'll have to do the same again in order to turn the water back into something useful. Not only that but you'll have to keep the water oxygenated!

Another problem is that filtration systems generally don't like organic material. If you've ever owned a fish tank you'll know that eventually the only thing you can do with the filter pads is throw them away: things start growing, leading to decreased performance and all manner of difficulties. This is a serious problem on a spaceship.

Next up you have the issue of feeding the fish. Whatever they eat, you'll have had to have grown it. Why not just eat whatever you're feeding the fish? It's simpler, far more energy efficient and avoids the whole 'poop in my nuclear reactor' scenario.

so, to sum up: If you're going to have fish living in your shielding water, don't try to use the water for everything else. Four separate smaller tanks are easier to deal with than one huge one, as you don't have to do everything in each tank.

Or: Just grow GM yeast.

Comment: +! for good arguments that keeping fish in the radiation shield isn't likely to be efficient, but against that - it might be fun! Or, at least, diverting. Having a job to do, such as fish farming, might be very important on a long space voyage. OK, you could just have fishtanks inside the ship, but maybe there isn't space and the water filled radiation barrier is handy. The necessary filtration and poop-cleaning might be make-work but make-work is good in the circumstances. Finally, which would you rather have:  *saumon poché à l’oseille* or GM Yeast Brick?

Comment: Keeping fish in the radiation shield is fine. Using the same water as propellant, fuel, drinking water, coolant and refinery fluid is a terrible idea. And I'd definitely prefer the fish. Possibly with a side of space-calamari.

Comment: Added more info to original post to address these comments. The filtration isn't an issue so much as the radiation might be. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: I can't stand fish myself, not my thing. But I'd probably still rather eat fresh fish than GM yeast brick. But I guess it's all about the recipe and the cook at the end of the day...

Comment: @smoj: My point wasn't that filtration couldn't be done, it was: 'why would you add that level of complexity to a system when you could just have multiple tanks?' In isolation you can set up the system so you only have to perform the filtration once rather than multiple times. In space, where any small problem can be a killer, simpler is better.

Comment: Also @smoj : the radiation from a sealed reactor isn't going to run into the same issues. As long as your fish aren't exposed to ridiculous levels of radiation directly then secondary transmission like you describe from Chernobyl isn't an issue (the highly radioactive compounds stay in the reactor chamber, where they should be). All you've got to deal with then is decaying isotopes of light elements, which aren't that bad (comparatively)

Comment: @Joe Bloggs As it happens, at the refinery where I worked, the water treatment side of things was pretty benign (compared to other parts of the refinery which were always breaking). The hardest thing you ever had to do was think up new things to Google while the water plant pretty much ran itself.  Being in the middle of the desert 1000km from the most isolated city in the world is a little like being in space I guess, so it had to be reliable. I agree with you though, 'keep it simple' is the best policy. Maybe multiple tanks.  Also re: closed system reactor and secondary transmission. Cheers!

Comment: Instead of filtering the water you run it through a high temperature, high pressure system that breaks down just about all contaminants.

Comment: Filters are almost forgettable for even just a fish tank if you're sticking to freshwater fish and don't care about keeping the water clear. There's plenty of microscopic plant life (common in ponds) that will do all the scrubbing the fish need, and are plants so help the oxygen content to boot. Main reason fish tanks need filters is because people also want to keep the fish visible.

Comment: @liljoshu that’s the kind of attitude that only works in a deep, well established ecosystem. A spaceship is not a deep, well established ecosystem.

Comment: @JoeBloggs The lime green fishtank in my front room whose filter I haven't changed in two years disagrees with you.

Comment: @liljoshu Do you top up the tank occasionally with fresh water filtered by whatever municipal grid you live on, or is your fish tank hermetically sealed?

Comment: @liljoshu: also: the point of this answer is not whether or not you can keep fish alive without filtration, it’s that there is no point keeping fish in the same tank as your shielding, potable water supply, coolant and fuel tank, as all that does is (paradoxically) adds complexity to the filtration you do need.

Comment: @JoeBloggs I do have to top off what evaporates, that's about it. As for keeping alive, if you need a filtration system at all is affected by how big this ship is.

Comment: @liljoshu: if you top off what evaporates then you’re drawing on a whole planetsworth of filtration and presumably a whole surface used for gas Exchange. The filtration systems aren’t affected by how big the ship is: they’re affected by how many systems need filtering for. One filter that feeds fish tank, drinking water and industrial systems is better than one for the fish tank and then one for each subsystem.

Comment: @JoeBloggs That might be the case if the it was anything besides water that was evaporating off. But that's all that's evaporating out. As long as you have a proper water cycle, filtering isn't needed.

Comment: @LorenPechtel A high temp/pressure system would certainly sterilise the water, but would do nothing to remove possibly toxic impurities, salts, suspended solids, soluble gasses etc. In water treatment, you want a low TDS level (total dissolved solids), and a low EC (electrical conductivity). These are indicators of impurities in the water. UV and chlorine are effective at sterilising water, but heat and pressure would work if you have excess power (say from a nuclear reactor). In fact circulating the water through the reactor cooling system would do that pretty well.

Comment: In mining processing/refinery plants, you often have multiple levels of water, for different uses.

Comment: Raw water is completely untreated. Bore water with hypersalinity, and whatever it comes with out of the ground.  Then Process Water, which is pretty much just lightly treated raw water, but may have anything from dead flies in it, and dust, to sulphuric acid that has leaked from a line somewhere, or crap from a washed out tank. This goes into the process tanks, thickeners, autoclaves etc, and is used for hosing up around the plant. Then there's potable water. Treated to food grade. Used for drinking, safety showers, and some processes.

Comment: Demineralised water is highly treated, expensive to make. It's potable water treated further so it's effectively pure H2O, with only a tiny fraction of 1% impurity. It will actually suck the electrolytes out of your body if you drink it. Effectively poisonous.

Comment: As much of the water as possible is reused, and kept in a closed loop. At the end of the process, the waste "Talings" (basically just mud with the gold, copper, iron or whatever taken out of it) are pumped as a slurry out to an area away from the plant. Often an old pit. The water in that slurry is pretty much the only water that isn't recovered.

Comment: @Smoj Remember, the contaminants are organic--enough heat and pressure will break them down.  All that's left is salts and when you condense the steam back to water you can get rid of those.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [image: Surviving Small Fishtank Ecosystem]

This is my 60 gallon fishtank. It's got plants, fish, and microflora that make it so I don't need a filter of any kind. Totally sustainable. Add another layer of water between it and the hull, and you'd have effective shielding and a regular supply of oxygen and edible food. The filter on this tank hasn't been changed in two years. (I'm a lazy butt, but a scientifically minded one, so I tried to make it into a balanced ecosystem.)

The microflora absorb a lot of the sunlight, as you can see you can't see that far through. Water filters sunlight much faster than atmosphere, a meter barrier would be way more than enough.

Comment: Umm....    Can you see if any fish are still alive in that?

Comment: Yep, they're all still alive. I'm actually having an easier time keeping them alive than before I started trying for the self-sustaining ecosystem.

Comment: @liljoshu That's kind of what I'm thinking about. Layering the system to keep the fish away from the hardest radiation, but having some way of reusing the shield water as a resource for life support, fuel etc. Maybe some kind of osmotic membrane between the layers...

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best radiation shields we have known are lead walls. The thicker, the better. If I were on the ship, I would want really thick (1-2 meter) lead walls between the engine room and the aquariums.The feasibility of fish being kept as edibles depends on the size of the aquarium (and the size of fish too, obviously).

Considering that your spaceship has a crew size of 150, and you can support of a population of 2000 fish which mature in 6 months, it could be a potentially viable food source for the crew. However if the crew was larger, or the fish were too less, they could only be used as a delicacy at times, but not an everyday food item on the table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will edit the original post to include more info.

Comment: Best in what regard? One meter of lead will block as much as 18 meters of water, except I can drink the water (and keep fish in it).

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_protection) wikipedia entry states: *On long duration manned missions, advantage can be taken of the good shielding characteristics of liquid hydrogen fuel and water.*

Comment: Also, in addition to what @Samuel said: lead has order of magnitude larger density than water so the actual benefit of lead is only a factor of two. Add that water can double as part of life support, can be replenished in space, and being liquid can absorb kinetic energy without breaking or fracturing, just fix then relatively thin tank, and water is better for long term missions, **if** you have the infrastructure to source it from space instead of lifting from Earth. Oh and did anyone mention water is a good propellant?

Comment: I'm not trying to downplay water's role on the whole. My point is that lead is the best choice for containing radiation. Advantage could be taken of liquid hydrogen's shielding characteristics, but liquefying hydrogen is a huge deal in terms of energy consumptions and storage conditions. You have to have walls everywhere in the spaceship between different chambers. Why not include a layer of lead in the walls around the radioactive materials chambers and then again around the aquariums chamber? It should be a practical solution.

Comment: The amount of water required for a refining operation would be huge. So a large tank would be required. I'm thinking dual purpose. In economically viable operations, you've got to squeeze everything out of what you have, no wastage. There is plenty of evidence of water in the asteroid belt (Ceres, the largest asteroid alone is speculated to have oceans under its surface). If not, then some of Jupiter's moons. If not, then comets.

Comment: Actually, lead is not a good shield against neutron radiation. Hydrogen (and thus water, hydrocarbons, etc.) is a good neutron shield. Against gamma, water provides about the same shielding as lead or depleted uranium when considered on a mass basis. Shielding against alpha and beta particles is very easy.

Comment: Another option I was looking at for interstellar flight is a shield made of ice built up around the front of the ship. For radiation, but also to dissipate the energy from micrometeorite impacts. You've got to carry water anyway, you might as well hang it frozen off the front of a ship, and give it an extra purpose.